# Is there any Haftarah that has all the te'amim/trope symbols?

Tags: trop-cantillation, haftarah

Is there any Haftarah that has all the te'amim/trope symbols? i will be transcribing melodies from a specific Hazzan who reads, and so i need to find every te'am that occurs so that way i can compile a list of all the melodies for the haftarah that this hazzan uses.

i'm not concerned with trope symbols that don't appear in any haftarot, as i'm trying to learn a system for haftarah chanting. If one could give either the least amount of verses required, or the least amount of haftarot required to cover all the symbols that would be greatly appreciated. i don't think there's much use in needed different combinations as the reader we have recordings for is very consistent.

Answer (score 9):

The minimum number of verses that you'd need is at most three.

[Yirmeyahu 32:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.32.8) (Haftara for Behar) to get Munach, Telisha-Gedola, Kadma, Azla, Zarka, Segol, Pazeir, Munach-Legarmeih, Revi'i, Gershayim, Darga, Tevir, Merkha, Tipcha, Etnachta, Zakeif-Gadol, Sof-Pasuk.

[Yeshayahu 55:10](http://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.55.10) (Haftara for fast days at Mincha) to get Telisha-Ketana, Pashta, Zakeif-Katan, Yetiv, Mahpach.

[Zecharia 3:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.3.2) (Haftara for Beha'alotecha) to get Merkha-Khefula.

Comment: If anyone finds a two-verse option I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Technically speaking this even has all four kinds of Munach.

Comment: I haven't checked, but does _B'haalos'cha_ give you all the trop? If so, it may be more convenient than a verse from here and a verse from there.

Comment: @msh210 No Zarka (at least). There's a Yetiv and Telisha-Ketana in that Haftara in different verses, so we could limit the number of Haftarot to 2 but then we'd need 4 verses.

Comment: [Daniyel 6:13](http://www.sefaria.org/Daniel.6.13) [Esther 3:12](http://www.sefaria.org/Esther.3.12) Kings 2:20:13/Isaiah 39:2 Jeremiah 33:11 have 18 out of 22 "usual" trop marks. I don't know of any with more.

Comment: There are no haftarot that have the "obscure" notes - shalshelet, yerach ben yom and karnei parah.

Answer (score -2):

Most Chumashim have a page at the very beginning, before the weekly Parshios, with all the trop symbols. There's a few rare ones in there - shalsheles, karnei parah, yerach ben yomo - which all appear a couple of times in the Torah but I don't believe appear in any Haftarah.

Comment: Whoever down voted my post, could you please explain why so I can improve it?

Comment: Doniel, while your answer is true, it doesn't technically answer the question. FWIW, I did not downvote, I am merely explaining what I assume the reason was. שבת שלום

Comment: The merchah chefula appears about 6 times in the Torah and once in Zechariah in a section that is read as part of a Haftorah.